# When using Rails 3.2.22.2, what is the highest Ruby Version I can use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm looking to upgrade a large application with many gems. It's currently on Ruby 1.9.3p551.

I've heard that I can upgrade to Ruby 2.2 but not any higher.

Is this version of Rails compatible with Ruby 2.2.5, alternatively, how can I find out the highest possible version supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from this [blog post](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2015/6/16/Rails-3-2-22-4-1-11-and-4-2-2-have-been-released-and-more/)

> Rails 3.2.22 includes all the commits from the 3-2-stable branch. This mean that now Rails 3.2 supports Ruby 2.2.

Since Rails 3.2 [doesn't receive bug fixes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/maintenance_policy.html#new-features) anymore (only severe security fixes) I would not expect updates to the Rails 3.2 branch that ensure Ruby 2.3 compatibility. Furthermore, Rails 3.2 reaches end of life when Rails 5.0 is released (what will be very soon, since 5.0.0.RC1 is already available).

Comment: Ruby 2.2.0 or Ruby 2.2.5?

Comment: Ruby uses [Semantic Versioning](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/12/21/ruby-version-policy-changes-with-2-1-0/), therefore Ruby 2.2.0 and 2.2.5 should be API compatibility, since 2.2.5 should only make backwards-compatible bug fixes. I think it should be safe to assume that Rails 3.2.22 works with Ruby 2.2.5. Another question you have to answer is: Is your app (aka the code you wrote) compatible with Ruby 2.2.x?

Comment: we had to make some changes with the YAMLer Syck vs. Psych. But those are done now.